# Changing image for button on hover?

Tags: html, css, forms

Hi I have a HTML button that is setup like this:

`<input type="image" src="derp.png">`

As the image is not assigned via CSS how am I meant to change it on hover?

Comment: JavaScript would be the way to go; is that acceptable?

Comment: @dqlopez I just want the image to change when the mouse hovers over the button.

Comment: @dqlopez I don't think that it is difficult to understand it. Most browsers have a default property of highlighting the button if your mouse hovers over it.

Comment: @DavidThomas I would go with Javascript but Im not familiar with using it to modify my HTML. If you could please provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: z-index might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following would work (though currently untested), it requires the alternate image to be stored in a custome `data-*` attribute in order that the script knows where to find it, and then stores the original `src` in a similar `data-*` in order to put it back on mouseout:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    input = inputs[i];
    input.onmouseover = function(){
        this.setAttribute('data-orig-image',this.getAttribute('src'));
        this.src = this.getAttribute('data-alt-image');
    };
    input.onmouseout = function(){
        this.src = this.getAttribute('data-orig-image');
    };
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vyKFd/).

Bear in mind the above requires your `input` to have the HTML form:

```
<input type="image" src="http://path.to/default/image.png" data-alt-image="http://path.to/mouseover/image.png" />​
```

---

**Edited** to add a CSS option, which is somewhat imperfect unfortunately, and requires that the `input` has no image set in its `src` attribute:

```
input[type=image] {
    background-image: url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 185px;
}
input[type=image]:hover,
input[type=image]:active,
input[type=image]:focus {
    background-image: url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/mandark.png);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vyKFd/1/).

Comment: hmm.. Thanks Ill play with it this seems to be a long way of doing it. But Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just corrected the demo; have a look at the linked demo. Should work.

Comment: The CSS option is defintely my favourite option and probably the one Ill go with as my HTML will still validate and is a bit simpler (to me at least) ;)

Comment: Awesome; only problem with that is that you'll need to specify all the various states per image input (which is only a problem if you've got lots of them, really).

Comment: Only issue here is that it always says "submit query" through the images. (also in the demo). Way around this is: HAVE a 'src' for the 'input': make a transparent gif that size and put it in it's place. Works flawlessly.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, surely the CSS option is not ideal, as it does not have the ALT tag fallback if there is no SRC defined. Accessibility and all.

Answer (score 16):

A very simple way:

`<input type="image" src="derp.png" onMouseOver="this.src='aderp.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='derp.png'">`

JSFiddle (demo): http://jsfiddle.net/E6xHr/

There are much more unobtrusive ways to do this, but this will work.

Comment: :) did you need it to validate?

Comment: No I just like it validating (Sense of accomplishment) but I'm not gonna waste days on one button =P Although I got the CSS method so its fine now. =D Thanks

Comment: Why would this not validate btw?

Comment: I just ran it through W3C as HTML5, and the only thing that was missing was an ALT tag. Once you add that in, it passes. `This document was successfully checked as HTML5!`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options that I can see:

1) CSS

```
input.change {
background-image:url(derp.png);
}

input.change:hover {
background-image:url(mouseover.png);
}
```

(Adding the class 'change' onto the input element from your example.)

2) JavaScript

```
<input type="image" src="derp.png" onmouseover="this.src='mouseover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='derp.png'">
```

Comment: Hmm Ill try your CSS method that you suggessted it seems clean and unobstructive. Thanks.

Comment: Nup The CSS method doesn't work. The javascript does but its not validator friendly =(

Answer (score 1):

Since most answers provided were JavaScript native or CSS based approached, I'll suggest a jQuery solution. You can simply use [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) in jQuery.

**jQuery script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#img1').hover(function() {
    $('#img1').attr('src','second_img.jpg');
  }, function() {
   // do something here
   alert('hovered out');
 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="img1" type="image" src="first_img.png">
```

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxSew/).

Comment: Thanks but Ive decided to stick with a CSS Method. =D

Comment: No worries. Just in case you'll stumble in jQuery solution someday :)

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to put an image under the button and have the alpha for the button background image transition set to 0 so that you can see the image under.