# Changing button image on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to have a page with 4 buttons, each in one quarter of the page. The buttons should have an image as their background, and this image should change when the button is hovered over. How is this done in CSS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple snippet that accomplishes the items you ask. I used jQuery's hover function to attach event handlers to modify the images.

I set 0 font-size, padding, and margin on the container (body) and used 50% width and 50vh (viewport height) to get 4 equal quadrant buttons.

```js
$('button').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x150');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></button>
<button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></button>
<button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></button>
<button><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></button>
```

Comment: It's good to help people but it's better to avoid answering such question that are too broad and provided 0 code and 0 effort. We will simply encourage people to post such questions again and again and they may thing that SO is a free coding service.

Comment: Jason, you must know that my knowledge with CSS is limited so I have no code to offer you other than that which is received. What properties should be used in CSS and/or HTML to properly scale images,  so that they may fit within their corresponding button. Furthermore I wish to accomadate each quadrant with a designated image and corresponding hover image so that each button is unique.

Comment: I also inquire into registering these buttons as links so that they function for the purpose of navigating to pages.

Comment: An update: I have found that by using <a href><button><img src="images/#" href="#"></button></a> I can create a link between the button and a webpage.

Comment: An update:I found a link that addresses a the problem of changing an image on hover: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331615/changing-image-for-button-on-hover